# flask init_db in app_context vs not? what is the difference?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have multiple apps and use flask_sqlalchemy with the style below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

However, in the test, all the app linked to the same database.

after I switch to the following style. Every app can linked to its own database.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
       db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

I did not understand why? If the second case is better, why it is not in the official doc?

credit: I copied the second style from https://hackingandslacking.com/demystifying-flasks-application-context-c7bd31a53817

Answer (score 0):

Each app you create has it is own context, using the below block of code:

```
with app.app_context():
   db.init_app(app)
```

means that you initialize those instances to that app context only and trying to access those instances somewhere else will result in the below error.

> RunTimeError: Working outside of application context.

You can read more about Flask app context [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/)